# Access Form Opening on Bottom of the Screen

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an access form with about 7 tabs on it. 
When I click on one of the tabs, the window automatically opens to the very bottom of the page for some reason.

I'm really not sure what's causing this... There is no VBA code stating to do this.

I tried implementing this code:

```
Private Sub Incident_Information_Click()
     Forms![PIR Form].[Claim Number].SetFocus
End Sub
```

And:

```
Private Sub TabCtl0_Click()
If Me.TabCtl0.Value = 2 Then
    Forms![PIR Form 2].[Claim Number].SetFocus
End If
End Sub
```

I hoped that when the user goes to the "Incident Information" tab, the window would automatically be set to the first control (in this case text box named "Claim Number").

Sometimes this works and sometimes it doesn't. The majority of the time, the screen still scrolls down to the bottom of the form.

Can anyone assist? I don't what's causing this issue and how to correct it.

Comment: So this is a normal Tab control, not a Navigation form? The form initially opens correctly but scrolls when tab is clicked? Is the first control TabIndex set to 0? Subform is in Single view? Really hard to analyze design issues without viewing the object.

Comment: Correct, just a normal tab control. The other tabs are pretty short, only a couple rows, but the tab that is giving me problems is much longer and requires you to scroll down to view everything. That's the issue. If the tab was shorter, I wouldn't care if the screen jumps to the bottom because the user wouldn't have to scroll up, but since this tab is longer, it forces the user to scroll up.

Comment: Sounds like the tab order is off for this tab, i.e. a control at the bottom is the first in the tab order, and so it gets the focus.

Comment: Didn't answer question about TabIndex. Suggest you check that property.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots with working and not working examples?

Answer (score 0):

Open the form in design view and select the controls (tab control) that are shown at the bottom of the screen.

Change this property: `Vertical Anchor` to `Top`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Tab Stop property to No for vertically long controls.

There are controls in some of my Tabs that are vertically long. Whenever I just clicked the tab, the scrollbar would go down. I changed Tab Stop property to No on a subform in one tab and a multiline textbox in another tab and it fixed the scrollbar jump problem.